# How to get a page array and category array going at the same time?

Tags: array

I'm using the code below to add a logo in the header of certain pages and I'm wodering if there a way to add the logo(sublogo.jpg) to certain categories as well as "page-one", "page-two" and so on?

```
    <div id="header-logo" onclick="location.href='<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>'" style="cursor: pointer;" >
    <?php if (is_page(array('page-one', 'page-two', 'page-three','page-four'))) $logo_image = 'subLogo.jpg';
    else $logo_image = 'mainLogo.jpg';?>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/<?php echo $logo_image;?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" />
    </div>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extend this line:

```
<?php if (is_page(array('page-one', 'page-two', 'page-three','page-four'))) $logo_image = 'subLogo.jpg';
```

with

```
|| is_category(array('cat-1', 'cat-2'))
```

so you get, for example:

```
<?php if (is_page(array('page-one', 'page-two', 'page-three','page-four')) || is_category(array('cat-1', 'cat-2')) ) $logo_image = 'subLogo.jpg';
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category